# Modify/transform data in Select-Object

Tags: powershell

Say I've got a list of items. I'd like to export to csv, but I want to do some calculations / modifications before I do so.

Basically, the setup looks like this:

```
PS C:\Files> gci
Directory: C:\Files

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        10/23/2014   6:03 PM      11084 Blob.txt
-a---        10/13/2014   1:32 PM      31591 dates.txt
-a---         2/11/2014   1:46 PM      11990 out.txt

PS C:\Files> $data = gci
```

And I can select the items I want to put into CSV easily enough. The actual Export-CSV part is omitted for brevity

```
PS C:\Files> $data | Select-Object FullName,name
```

But what I REALLY want to do is calculate a few columns and also include those in the CSV. Just as an example, say I want to count the '\' characters to get an idea of the folder depth. I think you can tell what I am trying here, even though it errors out.

```
PS C:\Files> $data | Select-Object FullName,name,FullName.Split('\').Count
Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '1'.
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 19):

What you need is a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) (thank you Ansgar Wiechers for correcting my terminology and providing a link) to do that for you. You can accomplish this in a Select command by creating a kind of impromptu hashtable like so:

```
PS C:\Files> $data | Select-Object FullName,name,@{name='FolderDepth';expression= {$_.FullName.Split('\').Count}}
```

That could be shortened to `@{n='Name';e={scriptblock}}` where `n` stands for name, and is interchangeable with `l` (short for label). `e` is short for expression.

Comment: They're called [calculated properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. What you are looking for is more complex `Select-Object` statement using [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx). Sample syntax:

`@{Label = "Calculation";Expression ={$_.FullName.Split('\').Count}}`

Then you insert this into a select statement, usually with other variables.

```
$data | Select-Object FullName,name,@{Label = "TheCount";Expression ={$_.FullName.Split('\').Count}}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Proposal (also a bit more readable then doing it in select):

```
$data | % {Add-Member -name FolderDepth -Value $_.FullName.split("\").Count -MemberType NoteProperty -InputObject $_} | select FullName,Name,FolderDepth
```

This adds a Property to $data which you can use further in the Pipeline with `$_.FolderDepth` just like any other property.

What makes this different is this property will also be available after the pipeline if you want to do stuff with it afterwards

Comment: A note on this, you need to add the `-Passthru` parameter to `Add-Member` or it will not pass the object down the pipeline to the `Select` cmdlet.